# Why to use foreign keys with no action on delete or update

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, myisam

I have a question of interest:

I have 2 tables in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) with `InnoDb`.
table `tbl_a` has a primary key, named `a_id`;
table `tbl_b` has a primary `b_id` and a foreign key on `tbl_a.a_id` with "`ON DELETE NO ACTION`".

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|  Table Name |  Primary Key  |  Foreign Key  |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|    tbl_a    |     a_id      |               |
|    tbl_b    |     b_id      |     a_id      |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

why should I still use InnoDb and foreign keys, if i don't really use the magic of foreign keys in the end in anyway?
Is there still a point of using
*[innodb](/questions/tagged/innodb) and foreign keys*
instead of
*[myisam](/questions/tagged/myisam) and no foreign keys*.
If I just do "`NO ACTION`" on deletes or updates?

I hope you got my point of interest :)

Comment: Doesn't it ensure that the foreign keys correspond to actual, valid rows?

Comment: If you delete foreign row your data is not complete, and you are going to have big mess in DB.

Comment: summary looks like, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` will stop invalid deletes/updates, so it is good to have

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `ON DELETE NO ACTION` means. It does *not* mean to suppress the foreign-key constraint.

When you delete a record that is referred to by a foreign key, InnoDB has the ability to take an automatic action to rectify the situation:

- it can `CASCADE`, meaning, delete the referring record. (This would make sense for something like `user_address.user_id`. If you hard-delete a user, you probably want to hard-delete all of the user's addresses as well.)
- it can `SET NULL`, meaning, clear out the referring key. (This might make sense for something like `file.last_modified_by`. If you hard-delete a user, you might want the file's last-modified-by to become simply "unknown".)

If you specify `NO ACTION`, you're telling InnoDB that you don't want it to take either of these actions. So InnoDB can't fix the situation for you; all it can do is reject the `DELETE` and return an error.

As a result, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` is actually the same as `ON DELETE RESTRICT` (the default).

(Note: in some DBMSes, and in standard SQL, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` is a bit different from `ON DELETE RESTRICT`: in those, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` means "accept the `DELETE` within the current transaction, but reject the whole transaction if I try to commit it before rectifying the problem". But InnoDB doesn't support deferred checks, so it treats `ON DELETE NO ACTION` exactly the same as `ON DELETE RESTRICT`, and always rejects the `DELETE` *immediately*.)

See §§[14.2.2.5 "FOREIGN KEY Constraints"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and [13.1.17.2 "Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.

Comment: ohhhh ok, thank you very much... well then I truly misunderstood "NO ACTION"

Comment: but why does phpmyadmin offer both: "NO ACTION" and "RESTRICT"? do they misunderstand it too?

Comment: @user1011116: Well, MySQL supports both notations, so I guess phpmyadmin feels that it should offer them both as well? And I could imagine a storage engine handling them differently -- some DBMSes do handle them slightly differently (as mentioned in the documentation I linked to) -- so perhaps phpmyadmin feels that it's more future-proof to let users choose.

Comment: I agree with the asker, here. "NO ACTION" does not communicate the same thing as "DEFAULT ACTION". To me, "NO ACTION" seems to indicate "don't do anything," which would also be nonsensical.

Comment: @ryvantage: I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is -- I'm not MySQL, so it doesn't make sense to argue with me about what it *should* mean -- but let me try to address it anyway . . . It's not that "NO ACTION" means "DEFAULT ACTION"; rather, it's that there's no default action. When you delete a row in a way that would violate the constraint, you can specify an action for MySQL to take to rectify the situation; but if you don't do so, then it won't take any action, so the statement continues to violate the constraint. So, it's rejected.

Comment: @ruakh, that confused me even further. Your original answer said `It means the same as ON DELETE RESTRICT (the default)`. But now you're saying it doesn't mean to do the default action?? I'm confused. And, yes, any hostility you may perceive towards you was indeed unintended. I even realized that the comment was not written well when I first wrote it and tried to edit it accordingly. Apparently I failed. Sorry.

Comment: @ryvantage: There's no default action: by default, it does no action, letting the error happen (due to the constraint violation). If you want to explicitly specify that there should be no action, and therefore an error, you can write `ON DELETE RESTRICT` or `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, but these are both equivalent to the default behavior, which is not to take any action, letting the error happen. If you still don't see it, then I'm not sure I can make it any clearer . . .

Comment: Thanks. I find this name pretty confusing. IIUC, "NO ACTION" means that the system DOES react to noticing that a foreign key constraint would be violated by the current mutation statement (i.e. update or delete): the reaction is to return to the state that existed prior to the (in progress) mutation being enacted. Also, IIUC, "NO ACTION" does what most people would consider "the most sensible thing", which esp makes sense, since "NO ACTION" is implied in the absence of explicit specified action.

Comment: @allyourcode If you want "no action" in that sense, why define the constraint in the first place?

Comment: @tobiv: I don't think allyourcode is suggesting that the DBMS should offer unenforced constraints as a DB feature; rather, (s)he's saying that `ON DELETE NO ACTION` is a poor name for what it does.

Answer (score 9):

The foreign key constraint even without `ON DELETE / UPDATE CASCADE` ensures that if you insert a  value into the child table, that it has a correctly matching value in the parent table (or is `NULL` if the FK column is nullable).  Attempting to insert an invalid value into the child table's FK column would result in error when the constraint fails, so your data integrity is protected.

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Defining the foreign key constraint also implicitly defines an index on the FK column in the child table, which although you could have manually defined the index, will improve joining performance.

`ON DELETE NO ACTION` (which is the same as omitting the `ON DELETE` clause) will actively *prevent* deletion of a parent row if it is referenced by any child table, not passively allow it to be deleted without affecting child rows.