# You have an error in your SQL syntax near ' '')' at line 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So guys, I got an error message :

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' '')' at line 1

From this codes, Whenever I click Add button
**todo.php**

```
<?php
include '../database/database.php';
session_start();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$querydisplay = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_id=$user_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $querydisplay);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>To Do List</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">To Do List <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <ul class="list-group text-left">
                        <?php while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :?>
                            <?php if($data['done'] == 0) : ?>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><span class="task_list"><?php echo $data['task'] ?></span><a href="../models/done_process.php?id=<?php echo $data['list_id']?>"><span class="label label-default">Mark As Done</span></a></li>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><span class="task_list"><strike><?php echo $data['task'] ?></strike></span><a href="../models/delete_process.php?id=<?php echo $data['list_id']?>"><span class="label label-danger">Delete</span></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="../models/newtask_process.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input name="newtask" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter New Task">
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      <footer class="footer text-center">
        <p>&copy; Company 2017</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**newtask_process.php**

```
<?php
include '../database/database.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $task = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newtask']);

if(!isset($user_id) || $user_id = "" || !isset($task) || $task = "")
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("You Write an Empty Task. Process Failed.");
              document.location="../views/todo.php";</script>';
}
else
{
    $queryinsert = "INSERT INTO todo (user_id, task) VALUES ($user_id, '$task')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $queryinsert))
    {
        header("Location: ../view/todo.php");
        exit();

    }
    else
    {
        die ('Error : ' .mysqli_error($conn));
    }

}


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Please help me debug this insert query or something like that.

I haven't even move to the update or delete query yet.

I already look the similiar question like this, and I already try them, but no success, 

Maybe there is something I miss

I know this is not safe way to execuse query (I dont use PDO or something like that).

But I'm just trying to get a hang of it, maybe later I will move to the PDO and OOP concept.

Comment: Which query is the one that's failing?  Your code is wide open to SQL injection, which means that you're not really controlling the syntax being used and the values could change that syntax at runtime.  When the error occurs, what's the actual query being executed?  That is, after replacing the variables, what's the resulting query that's sent to the database?

Comment: can you do `echo $queryinsert;`

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This will also fix the pesky quoting issue that you're running into.

Comment: I believe the $queryinsert is the one that failing

Comment: Yes it is. You can echo out `$queryinsert` to see where the error lies. I'm guessing it's a quoting issue. Using prepared statements with bind_param will fix it where `mysqli_real_escape_string` will not.

Comment: @aynber, this is what happened when I echo $query insert. 
INSERT INTO todo (user_id, task) VALUES (, '')
 Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '')' at line 1

Comment: Looks like user_id and task are empty. If you look at your `if` line, you're using single quotes, which is the assignment operator. Use `==` instead, use `empty` instead of the isset and empty string checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this line is rewriting your variables:

```
if(!isset($user_id) || $user_id = "" || !isset($task) || $task = "")
```

Change it to use the empty function instead:

```
if(empty($user_id) || empty($task))
```

Unless one of them will be 0 or null, then this will work and your variables will pass through.

Comment: This is actually the solution. How the hell is it about the checking condition? I thought the $queryinsert is the problem.

Comment: It looked that way until you echoed out the query and your variables were empty. The if statement passes through because both variables were set, and the blank string assignments worked.

Comment: should I include the isset checking condition too? Or is it just the same?

Comment: No, it's the same. [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks to make sure that the variable is set and that it is not null or false and does not contain an empty string, or 0.

Answer (score -2):

this could work `$querydisplay = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_id='$user_id'";`

Comment: The error is on their INSERT query, not their SELECT query. The parenthesis in the error gives it away.

Comment: @aynber Then did you try surrounding $user_id with inverted commas or remove inverted commas surrounded to $task

Comment: Why are you asking me? It's not my code. I'm just pointing out which query is throwing the error.

Comment: There is no problem with $querydisplay.

Answer (score -2):

possibly this:

```
$queryinsert = "INSERT INTO todo (user_id, task) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "', '" . $task . "')";
```

Comment: I got this error. Error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`todolist`.`todo`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: That means we're one step closer to the answer :) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096790/why-to-use-foreign-keys-with-no-action-on-delete-or-update) for more info on this foreign key constraint business