# update between three tables using left join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, and want to update some fields in these tables but the query doesn't work

This is my Query:

```
UPDATE 
customers cust
    left JOIN
contract cont ON cust.Customer_id = cont.Customers_Customer_id
    left JOIN
payments pay ON cust.Customer_id = pay.Customers_Customer_id
SET 
cust.Customer_Name = 'Sara',
cust.Customer_id = '1201941718', 
cust.Customer_Mobile1 = '01258863956',
cust.Customer_Phone = '0224598755', 
cust.Customer_Mail = 'sara@gmail.com', 
cont.Customers_Customer_id = '1201941718', 
pay.Customers_Customer_id = '1201941718'
where cust.Customer_id = '2';
```

The error:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`alhawel`.`payments`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_Payments_Customers1` FOREIGN KEY (`Customers_Customer_id`)
>   REFERENCES `customers` (`Customer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE
>   NO ACTION)

Comment: This error is pretty self-explanatory, don't you think?

Comment: I update the foreign key but i don't know why this message appears?

Comment: This is data integrity issue, you set a foreign key constraint in the `pay` table that preventing you from updating the rows. I don't know the structure or the logic behind your DB structure so I can't be more specific unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one or more `payments` associated to `customer_id = 2`

When you update `customer_id = 2` to `customer_id = '1201941718'` that payment become orphan and the FK constraint detect the integrity violation.

What you can do is:

- insert new Customer_id = '1201941718'
- update payments to Customer_id = '1201941718'
- delete Customer_id = 2

But in db you shouldn't change the id of a record. There is no benefit for it . If you need add some metadata to the entity add another field and leave the PK alone.

Comment: Not an expert, so I'm not sure about it - But what about `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? Would it not then update the referencing rows as well?

Comment: @AlonEitan That could work, here is an answer related to that topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807004/how-to-update-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

I believe it isn't working because of the ON UPDATE NO ACTION in the foreign key. When you are updating the Customer_id in the Customer table, the foreign keys pointing to that will no longer be valid.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12096859/8070411) answer deals with ON DELETE NO ACTION but it applies to update as well. I think you will need to modify the constraint to fix this error (which may not be the right thing to do for other reasons, knowing more about the schema may get a better answer).